# Passing *arg arguments from list

Tags: python, function, arguments, argument-passing

I'm in a situation when I have to call one function foo:

```
def foo(arg1,arg2,*args):
    pass
```

The problem is that I have the `*args` arguments stored during computing as a list.

Like this:

```
a = 'arg1'
b = 'arg2'
list_of_args = ['arg3','arg4','arg5']
```

How can I call the function foo with this arguments to be like:

```
foo('arg1','arg2','arg3','arg4','arg5')
```

I could do this:

```
foo(a,b,list_of_args[0],list_of_args[1],list_of_args[2])
```

but it does not solve this problem because length of `list_of_args` depends on  a situation so it could be:

```
foo(a,b,list_of_args[0],list_of_args[1],list_of_args[2],list_of_args[3],...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply unpack the list with `*`:

```
a = 'arg1'
b = 'arg2'
list_of_args = ['arg3','arg4','arg5']

foo(a, b, *list_of_args)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call, `expression`
>   must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated
>   as if they were additional positional arguments

Comment: Oh, man! Thanks, it was so simple. I've tried many tricks like ', '.join(args) etc. Thanks